# Extracting values of clustering criteria from "kml" R package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am using the `kml` package in `R` to cluster my data. I have obtained the plot that shows the estimated clustering criterion values. But what I would like to obtain are the raw values of the criteria for each number of clusters for further use.

R code

```
cat12 <- kml(cldhrsT12, 2:6, nbRedrawing = 20, toPlot = 'both')
plotAllCriterion(cldhrsT12)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with `the raw values of the criteria`?

Comment: I mean the estimated values of the criteria that are used in the plot. They are obviously generated to enable to plot to be produced but I can't see how to obtain the values. I thought I would be able to use the View(some data frame name) to see what the values are but the documentation doesn't provide any information on what this data frame would be called or even if there is one.

Comment: Can you please provide a specific example? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you might want to have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So far, I can only guess tha tyou might want to have a look at [getClusters](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kml/kml.pdf)

Comment: my apologies. I was under the impression that if someone was comfortable with the kml package, they would have understood my question.